# Please verify my layout: bottom button keeps coming up over keyboard

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout which does almost what I want. There's just one bug regarding the button at the bottom. I should stay at the bottom at all times. But whenever I bring up the soft-keyboard the button will be displayed above the keyboard. This is not what I want but it should become covered by the keyboard.

Moreover, I'd be happy if you could comment on how the layout's built.

Thanks,
steff

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/l_layout_tags"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:text="TAGS:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/actv_tags"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn_add_tag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:onClick="addTag"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/sv_scroll_contents"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/l_layout_tags"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="2000" >
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/t_layout_contents"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:paddingRight="5dip">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tr_template">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_blank"
                android:src="@android:color/transparent" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/et_content1"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:maxWidth="200dp"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/l_layout_media_btns"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/sv_scroll_contents" >
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:onClick="takePicture" />
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn_video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn_audio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" />
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn_sketch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
</LinearLayout> 

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn_save_note"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml.

This way, the software keyboard won't resize your layout and your button will stay under it.
Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) to get a better idea about different soft keyboard modes.

Comment: And could you comment on the layout itself? Is it completely redundant?

Thanks, mate

Comment: And one more thing: when I fill the automatically resizing EditText (what I want) it starts to be covered by the afore mentioned button at some point.
How can I modify the Layout in such a way that the button stays at the bottom and does not cover anything?

Comment: Old question, I know. But if you want to keep your EditText above the bottom buttons then you can declare the button layout layout_alignParentBottom="true" and the ScrollView layout_above="@id/l_layout_media_btns" in addition to the layout_below. That tells the layout manager that it should be sandwiched

Comment: It restrict scroll action!! @Dimtar

Comment: I have same problem if it is Dialog ?? how to add                                                            ```                                                                                                                                          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"                                                                      ```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. In which I have to show one button at bottom of screen always. I solved the problem of button is coming up of the keyboard in the following way:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:background="@color/white"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   >
       <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/ff"
        >
                 .......
       </ScrollView>

       <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSigninProblem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
            android:layout_below="@+id/ff"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"           
            android:text="Problem Signing in?"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```