# Android AdjustPan issue

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

My layout has a editText and a TextView in a relative layout aligned to the top of the parent. Then a scrollview that is from the bottom of rhe relativeLayout to the bottom of the screen with a 50dp margin at the bottom. In that 50dp I have a linearLayout with an ad. I wanted the ad to stay at the bottom when the soft keyboard opened, so I added the adjustPan to the manifest. However, now when the soft keyboard opens, it pushes the relativeLayout at the top off the screen. Any solution?

Comment: the layout.xml or the manifest? The issue I'm having is that I have a overarching relativeLayout, then a scrollview and when I open the keyboard, the scrollview then just gets shifted up and everythin above the scrollview you can no longer see

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your activity tag **AndroidManifest.xml**. And also go through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433432/please-verify-my-layout-bottom-button-keeps-coming-up-over-keyboard)

Comment: I do have the adjustPan, thats what began causing the issues