# When software keyboard shows, activity is "moved up" - only sometimes. Why?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

Question is pretty simple - I have an activity, there is an textview or edittext inside, and when I focus on it, software keyboard show. That's fine. But sometimes (I can't se any logic here) is whole activity layout like moved up or how to say it. It's very rarely, but it happens time to time.

Surely many of us have same experiences and I'm asking why this unpredictably behaviour happens and how to force software keyboard act always in same way? Have anybody experiences with this?

Comment: i believe whenever your edittext is focused, the activity moves up - sharing screen with virtual keyboard.

Comment: Please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433432/please-verify-my-layout-bottom-button-keeps-coming-up-over-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can control it by setting the attribute android:windowSoftInputMode of your activity in the manifest file.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Add   `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your `Activity`  in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to the activity in the `Manifest.xml` file.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look at the [`android:windowSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) flag, that you can specify in your `<activity>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Maybe you should use `adjustPan`.